# Asp.Net - When does it restart the application

Tags: asp.net

I know that whenever you add/remove/modify any file in the "App_Code", "App_GlobalResources", and "bin" directories that ASP.NET will recompile and essentially restart the application.

My question is : "What happens to any threads currently executing durring the change?"

Do they finish? Is a Thread.Abort Exception thrown?

What happens if the application itself makes a change in any of those directories?

Comment: This goes for web.config, too.  Touching web.config is a handy way to force a recycle when you don't have access to IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All currently executing threads are finished gracefully before recompilation.

[Here's the docs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/24e3c22e-79a9-4f07-a407-dbd0e7f35432.mspx?mfr=true):

> When a worker process requests a
>   recycle, the WWW service initiates an
>   overlapped recycle, creating a new
>   worker process to replace the old one.
>   While the new worker process is
>   starting, the old process continues to
>   serve requests. After the new process
>   starts and initializes successfully,
>   the WWW service instructs the old
>   worker process to shut down. At this
>   point, the old worker process stops
>   accepting new requests from HTTP.sys
>   and begins to shut down. The WWW
>   service allows the old worker process
>   a configured time period in which to
>   finish processing its requests before
>   the worker process is shut down. The
>   WWW service terminates the worker
>   process if it fails to shut down
>   within the configured time.